# Does “comme on était à New York” mean “since” or “as though”?

Tags: sens, traduction, anglais, conjonctions, comparaison-de-langues

Quote:

> — Je sais que tu pars souvent avec lui, mais dis-moi franchement, êtes-vous allés chez le même coiffeur ?
>
> — As-tu l’intention de me faire un interrogatoire ? Car si c’est le cas, je vais dire toute la vérité, rien que la vérité... Ha, ha, ha voila. **Comme on était à New York**, je suis allé me faire couper les cheveux avec une bande de copains. Voila tout.

With my knowledge of the French language, I could actually think of two ways of translating that piece. You see, my dictionary says that the word **comme** can mean both *since* and *as though* at the same time. But that fact leads to two seemingly different translations that are actually contradictory in meaning:

> since we were in New York
>
> as though we were in New York

In English, these two sentences have meanings that are quite different. So, my question is how do I go about resolving this issue? Which translation is correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Comme*** has several meanings in French, but not the second one of your question which would require ***si***, as already stated by petitrien.

In the expression "***Comme*** on était à New York", it can mean:

> ***De la même façon*** qu'on était à New York,...   ("like, the same way": but it doesn't work in this sentence)

or

> ***Puisqu***'on était à New York,...  ("since, because": likely meaning here)

or

> ***Alors*** qu'on était à New York,...  ("while": rarer literary meaning)

The [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/comme) states that it is sometimes difficult to guess whether the second or the third meaning was intended:

> Rem. 3. Il est quelquefois difficile de faire le départ entre *comme* causal et *comme* temporel, *comme* glissant vers la valeur de morph. de la circonstance gén. (cf. supra III). *Au bout d'un moment, comme il se taisait mais qu'il avait l'air bien calme, je lui dis...* (G. Duhamel, *Tel qu'en lui-même*, 1932, p. 158 ds Sandf. t. 2 1965, § 196).

Answer (score 4):

The meanings are indeed quite different but *As though we were in New York* is the translation of *Comme **si** on était à New York* and not *Comme on était à New York*.  There is no ambiguity in French.

Comment: This is exactly as in English, of course: “as we were in New York, I went to get a haircut” is very different from “as if we were/had been in New York, I went to get a haircut”, but only the presence or absence of _if_ disambiguates.